# Create links out of imploded plain text

Tags: wordpress

I'm completely open on how to do this:

I have the line:

```
echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));
```

Which is outputting this:

```
Branding, Web, Print
```

I have 20 or so options it can output depending on what checkboxes were ticked.

At the moment, what it's outputting is just plain text. How can I make each tag a link? The link would need to be unique per tag so:

```
<a href="tags/design/branding">Branding</a>, <a href="tags/design/web">Web</a>, <a href="tags/marketing/print">print</a>
```

UPDATE:
This is what I have working currently, it's slightly different to your's but again it has the same problem of not being able to differentiate between the design or marketing link, here's the [test page](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/our-work/dtr-medical/):

```
                    <?php
$categories = get_field('categories');
$elements = array();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    //do something
    $elements[] = '<a href="/tags/design/' . strtolower($category) . '" title="' . $category . '">' . $category .'</a>';
}
echo implode(',', $elements);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates the links:

```
<?php
$categories = get_field('categories');
$elements = array();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    //do something
    $elements[] = '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}
echo implode(',', $elements);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
    $field_array = get_field('categories'); //get_field() return an array
    foreach ($field_array as $single){      //for each term of the array
       $categorie_slug = sanitize_title($single);   // clean the title from space, uppercase ...
       echo '<a href="tags/design/'.$categorie_slug.'">'.$single.'</a>';
    }
```

If you're using basic wordpress tags, use this:

```
$field_array = get_the_tags();  // get all tags
foreach ($field_array as $single){      //for each term of the array
   echo get_tag_link($single->term_id);
}
```

Comment: @Joeyjoejoe Thanks for that. If you look at the print link in the code example it has the link tags/marketing/ rather than tags/design which Branding and Web has. Is there a way I can decide which link it takes by matching the tags or something???

Comment: They're just pages with all the different tags as subpages

Comment: What re you attempting to do with this function?

Comment: I want all tags within the design section to have the link <a href="tags/design/'.$categorie_slug.'">'.$single.'</a> and all the tags within the marketing section to have the link <a href="tags/marketing/'.$categorie_slug.'">'.$single.'</a>. At the moment everything will just get redirected to the design section.

Comment: Are they basic wordpress tags or custom taxonomy?

Comment: The checkboxes were created using this plugin - http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Could you post the complete template or function code please?

Comment: You're using this code inside a loop when displaying a particular post or page?

Comment: No that's purely the code, anything that may look a bit strange is probably down to the custom field plugin.

Comment: I think you should use custom taxonomies instead of custom field. Creating a taxonomy named "design" with "branding" "web" etc as term of it. Custom field are used to attach data to a post/page, not to categorize that post/page.

Comment: @Joeyjoejoe I'll have a play and see what I come up with.